# how to export images to word file?

Tags: python, ms-word

I am working on a script which saves images to word file. I have been able to create a function to export images.

```
def exp_images():  #export images to word file
    document = Document()
    paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
    script = paragraph.add_run()
    script.add_text('This is a test sentence')
    script.add_picture('image1.png', width=Inches(6.5))
    document.save('demo.docx')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    exp_images()
```

The only issue I am facing is how to call that function repeatedly, and the function must save image to new line, and must not overwrite the existing image.
So, I just need help with this.
Thanks

Comment: What does "save image to new line" mean?

Comment: @Cobra Lets say you save an image in a word file, it gets copied to the first line of ms-word. Then, when you want to export another image to the same ms-word file, the new image should be saved below the original image and not overwrite the existing image in first place.

Comment: In that case I refer you to the documentation for the module you're using for Microsoft Word document processing. This is not a Python issue *per se*

Comment: The reason I have included python is, I am doing this task with help of python. I have several images and I just want to save them to word file, in an ordered manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass all the images to your function, iterate all of them, append them to the document and finally save the document.

```
def exp_images(images):  # export images to word file
    document = Document()
    paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
    script = paragraph.add_run()
    script.add_text('This is a test sentence')

    # loop through a list of images and add each one to the document
    for image in images:
        # add a line break between the text and the image
        script.add_break(WD_BREAK.LINE)
        # add the image to the document
        script.add_picture(image, width=Inches(6.5))

    document.save('demo.docx')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # call the exp_images function multiple times, loop through a list of images and add each one to the document
    images = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png']:
    exp_images(images)
```